# Sublime Git Keybindings

Tags: git, sublimetext2, key-bindings

I am using Git with Sublime 2. I added a couple of keybindisng which are working fine. However the "git push" does not.

the first 2 will work but the 3rd doesn't

```
{ "keys": ["f1"], "command": "git_quick_commit" },
{ "keys": ["f2"], "command": "git_log" },
{ "keys": ["f3"], "command": "git_push" }
```

Also, I couldn't find information about how to add keybindings for git checkout (a specific branch) and git merge (a specific branch). Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [Git](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Git) plugin from [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/). The list of available commands is contained in the files [Default.sublime-commands](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/blob/master/Default.sublime-commands) (for commands that appear in the command palette) and [Main.sublime-menu](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/blob/master/Main.sublime-menu) (for commands that appear in the menu).

If you check in the `Default.sublime-commands` file, the following are the commands that do a push, so you can select the one that you're interested in binding to the key. Note that for a couple of them you will also need to include the `args` as well.

```json
{
    "caption": "Git: Push",
    "command": "git_raw", "args": { "command": "git push", "may_change_files": false }
},
{
    "caption": "Git: Push Current Branch",
    "command": "git_push_current_branch"
},
{
    "caption": "Git: Push Tags",
    "command": "git_raw", "args": { "command": "git push --tags", "may_change_files": false }
}
```

There are no defined commands for being able to check out or merge with a specific branch, though.

Possibly you could use the `git_raw` command to do this, passing it the arguments that you would provide to git on the command line, but I don't know if that's generally safe in that the state of things (e.g. the status bar) might get out of sync as far as the plugin is concerned.